# calling c# dll which connects to a webservice from delphi, but the config file is not being used

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, app-config

I have to write an dll in c# which connects to a webservice, reads some values from that webservice und populates a databasetable with it. The dll should than be used by a delphi application.

I have managed to use the DLLExport-Attribute to publish the functions inside my dll and make delphi able to use them. The problem seems to be, that the app.config (where the information for the webservice seems to come from) is not being used when i call my functions from delphi.

C# DLL:

```
namespace SomeDLL
{
    [DllExport]
    public static bool GetClients(int userId, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string url)
    {
        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

            using (var client = new SomeWebserviceClient()) 
            using (var scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
            {
                var someData = client.GetSomeData();
                //Insert data to db
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"{e.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return false;
        }
    }    
}
```

I can use this dll inside an C# consoleapplication like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {    
            var id = 1;
            var url = "bla";

            SomeDLL.GetClients(id, url);            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {e}");
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine so far. But when i try to call this function from delphi like this:

```
function GetClients(userId: Integer; url: String) : Boolean; stdcall; external 'SomeDLL.dll';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var bResult: Boolean;
begin
  try
    bResult := GetClients(1, 'bla');

    if bResult
      then RichEdit1.Text := 'true'
      else RichEdit1.Text := 'false';

  except on e: Exception do
    RichEdit1.Text := e.Message;
  end;
end;
```

I get the error

> Could not find endpoint element with name and contract

This is the same error i get from my console application if i delete the app.config (which i copied from my dll-project) from the console project. I have already tried to copy the SomeDLL.dll.config which c# created together with the someDLL.dll file into the directory where the delphi application is located, but it seems like it still fails to use the config file.

If i delete the part of my dll where the webservice is used, there are no errors. So i guess the problem really comes down to the webservice not being able to work correctly without the app.config.

Any ideas how i can make this work?

Comment: "i get from my console application if i delete the app.config (which i copied from my dll-project) from the console project" -- Sherlock Holmes you are not. Debug your program and stop guessing.

Comment: _"The dll should than be used by a delphi application."_ - _Bad_ Idea. Wouldn't it be _way_ easier to write this in Delphi all along? Or at least C/C++ - something Delphi plays along with more smoothly?

Comment: @Blindy Yeah im definitly not some kind of Sherlock Holmes... But if you are such a genius, you might be able to help me. I already tried to debug. When i debug my console application everything works fine. Some questions here suggest, that the error occurs if the app.config is not available, which i confirmed by deleting it from my console application and getting the same error the moment i try to create the webservice client.

Comment: @Fildor Yeah that was also my first thougth. But the webservice does base on some wsdl file, which references other documents for it's datatypes. Delphi seems to be not able to create a webservice client if the wsdl file references other files. At least this is what i got told (I am not developing the delphi part). The delphi developers in my company already tried to merge the wsdl file with the other files, but had no success.

Comment: Thing is: Using the .Net DLL from a .Net Console App is a whole different Game than using it from a Delphi context. You _may need_ to jump some extra hoofs to properly load that library and create the appropriate runtime environment for it. If you can, I'd really suggest to do a little "Proof Of Concept" Dll + Executing Delphi for C++, maybe. Or put your focus on how to load and use managed .Net libraries in Delphi.

Comment: What I've actually seen in the past (even if I didn't like it): Delphi Code started out-of-process dotnet CLI tool and then digested the output. (Maybe as a "Alamo-Solution")

Comment: I suggest you write your C# code as a COM object that can be called by native code like Delphi. Or better, write everything in Delphi which is able to consume web services.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their help. I have found a solution. Not a solution to the question i have asked here, but on how to import the wsdl files inside delphi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have found a solution. Not for the problem of my question, but for the underlying problem...

The problem was, that delphi was not able to import the wsdl file, because the file itself was import datatypes from other xsd files. Delphi would create some methods, but alle datatypes from the xsd files were not present. The delphi team already tried to use this [WSDLMerge-Tool](https://github.com/lenardg/WSDLMerge) to merge the xsd-files into the wsdl file. But they reported, that it didn't work.

I downloaded the Tool myself and tried to use it. The tool seems to run without problems when using a local file. But the merged file was the same as the inputfile. So no merge has been done.

I was able to use it correctly by setting the targetframework to .net Framework 4.6.2 and using the webadress for the wsdl file. I still got an errormessage, that there is some conflict with ssl-certificates. I added this:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
```

line to ignore the ssl certificate validation. Running the tool now works again and the files are correctly merged. I was able to import the new merged wsdl-file in delphi and everything works now. I sent the merged wsdl file to the delphi team and they can now use the webservice on their own...